# Send email on ldap creation

Tags: bash, ldap, cron, openldap

I have an LDAP server setup on a server running Debian 7 and I wanted to make it send out an email whenever a new user was created on that LDAP.

I thought a cronjob would be best, but I have no idea how to do a search for recent creations.

Mail doesnt have to be too complex, just something along the lines of

```
welcome,
your username is: XXXX
you are in group: YYYY
```

and this will be sent to `commonName`@domain.com

any ideas/starting points on how to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make this a part of the user creation process, where it belongs.

If you want/must do it in a separate way, I would simply either add a custom schema with a field like `WelcomeSent` or (ab)use an unused field for this purpose and set it to `true` if the mail has been sent. You then write a simple cron job searching for user records with this field not set to true, send the mail and update this field. Obviously, you would set this field to true for all existing users in order to avoid confusion when introducing this.

I would not try to do this with a date field (or the update/creation date metadata records), as this is susceptible to race conditions (among other problems).